# Xtermjs get text

Tags: xtermjs

Using xterm.js, how do you get the text in the console (the text entered with `term.write(...)` or other methods).

Getting the textContent of the HTML does not work, because html handles whitespace differently and because xtermjs handles colors differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are referring to is the contents of the terminal's buffer.

As of now (xterm.js 3.2) there is no public API to retrieve the contents of the buffer, so you will have to work your way around this.

Attempting to retrieve the contents via the DOM will not work. Xterm.js uses a canvas element since version 3.0, instead of DOM div elements and text nodes, for performance.

The best way to do this with a public API is by listening to the [`data` event](https://xtermjs.org/docs/api/terminal/#data) and work with that. The `data` event is emitted when a chunk of data is being dispatched to the terminal for handling.

Answer (score 0):

A short solution when `rendererType` is `'dom'`

```js
let terminal = new Terminal({
  cols: 60,
  rows: 60,
  useStyle: true,
  rendererType: 'dom', // default is canvas, use dom
});
let terminalBuffer = Array.from(terminal.element.querySelectorAll(".xterm-rows>div")) 
  .map(e=>Array.from(e.querySelectorAll("span"))
  .map(e=>e.textContent).join("") ).filter(e=>e!="").join("\n")
console.log(terminalBuffer.trim())
```